# nodejs arrow function not returning expected value

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, aws-sdk

I'm using the aws-sdk to upload a message to kinesis. It works fine but i'm trying to solve for when the action does not work (due to internet being down or something).

Here is the code i'm running.

```
  const returnValue = kinesis.putRecord(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      logger.info(err);
      return err;
    } else {
      logger.info(data);
      return data;
    }
  });

  console.log(returnValue);
```

I expect to get back the err or data. Instead what I get back is a Huge json of what I assume is the kinesis.PutRecord request itself.

Any ideas on why i'm not getting data returned to my returValue variable?

The console logs data and error just fine.

UPDATE:

as pointed out in the comments, I needed to wrap the function in a promise. I also put it in a try catch since if you throw a "reject" without a catch you get an unhandled promise rejection.

Updated code here:

```
  try {
    const returnValue = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      kinesis.putRecord(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          logger.info(err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          logger.info(data);
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    });
    logger.log(returnValue);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
    return error;
  }
```

Comment: The arrow function is a callback function. The value that `returnValue` has is the function itself and it will print immediately even before kinesis function has time to go to AWS and return data. If you need data in `returnValue`, put the kinesis function in a Promise and use async/await

Comment: THANKS! That did it. I added the fixed code to the main post